# React Hooks setState function is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this error in React Hooks. The function exists but every time I type something in to the search bar I get this TypeError.

> TypeError : setSearchField is not a function

Here's the code for reference :

```
export default function StudentAPI() {
    const [searchField, setSearchField] = ('');
    const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

    const getStudents = async () => {
        return axios
        .get("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
        .then((res) => {
            setStudents(res.data.students);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getStudents();
    }, []);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchField(e.target.value);
    }
    const filteredStudents = students.filter((student) => {
        console.log(student.firstName);
        // return student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        // student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    })
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <SearchBox 
                placeholder={'Search by name'}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                value={searchField}
            />
            {filteredStudents.length > 0 ? filteredStudents.map((student) => {
                return <Student key={student.id} student={student}/>;
            }) : students.map((student) => {
                return <Student key={student.id} student={student}/>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
    
};
```

Comment: please put the code here to see what is the problem

Comment: where is the **setSearchField** definition ?

Comment: added the code now. sorry

Comment: i think you must use useState hook  **const [searchField, setSearchField] = usestate('');**

Comment: Like you did for the students state

Comment: you forget to type useState('')

Comment: wow you gotta be shitting me LOL I can't believe It was right in front of me.. THANK YOU

Comment: that's happens sometimes. enjoy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the hook useState

```
 const [searchField, setSearchField] = usestate('');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have the state declaration above
const [searchField,setSearchField]=useState()

Answer (score 2):

You have an error because `useState` is not written!

You must change

```js
const [searchField, setSearchField] = ('');
```

to

```js
const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');
```